# How to stop method that loops over array?

Tags: javascript, typescript, function, oop, methods

I have a method that runs a setInterval that calculates a number (a counter) every second, based on a given value.
I also have a method that stops the interval.

However, when the given value is an array, it only stops calculating the last value of the array...all the other values keep running.

```
class Helpers {
  static interval: number[];
  static filtered: [];


 static start(value: Vehicle): void {   
    Helpers.interval = setInterval(value.calculateSpeed, 1000, value);
  }


  static stop() {
    clearInterval(Helpers.interval);
  }


  static iterateArray() {

      for (let i = 0; i < Helpers.filtered.length; i++) {
        Helpers.start(Helpers.filtered[i]);
      } 
  }


static iterateStop() {
      for (let i=0; i < Helpers.filtered.length; i++) { 
          Helpers.stop();
      }
  }
}




<button onclick="Helpers.iterateArray()">Start</button>
<button onclick="Helpers.iterateStop()">Stop</button>
```

The stop() method works if there is only 1 element in value:Vehicle - if there are more only stops the last one.
The last method (iterateStop()) was my last stupid attempt to solve this problem.

Any help would be very much appreciated!

Comment: you need to pass the interval value to `stop()`,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to push the value onto the array instead of assigning it to the array then when you call stop you need to pass the interval to the method. Also, don't forget to initialize the two arrays.

See my modifications below:

```
class Helpers {
  static interval: number[] = [];
  static filtered: [] = [];

  static start(value: Vehicle): void {   
    Helpers.interval.push(setInterval(value.calculateSpeed, 1000, value));
  }

  static stop(interval: number) {
    clearInterval(interval);
  }

  static iterateArray() {
    for (let i = 0; i < Helpers.filtered.length; i++) {
      Helpers.start(Helpers.filtered[i]);
    } 
  }

  static iterateStop() {
    for (let i=0; i < Helpers.interval.length; i++) { 
      Helpers.stop(Helpers.interval[i]);
    }
    // Maybe clear one or both of the arrays here?
    // This is up to you and how your app works.
    // Helpers.interval = []
    // Helpers.filtered = []
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for you help! I just tried this but it wont stop. It continues calculating...now not even the last element is stopped. :(
(If I remove the arrays it throws an error: "Cannot read property 'push' of undefined"

Comment: Made a fix to `iterateStop`, I was looping over the wrong array there. Try now.

Comment: Your welcome! If you see my note at the bottom, you probably want to clear `Helpers.interval` once you stop them because when you run it again it will just append more items to a list of items that no longer exist.